# Does it make sense to use zookeeper in masterless architecture?

Tags: monitoring, apache-zookeeper, distributed, master-slave, consistent-hashing

In distributed set up using consistent hashing,eg. distributed cache implementation using consistent hashing, how can we manage the multiple nodes? By managing I mean, monitoring health and adjusting loads when one of server dies or new added and similar stuff.

Here we dont have any master as all peer nodes are same. So gossip protocol is on way. But I want to understand can we use zookeeper to manage nodes here? Or zookeeper can only be used where we need master-slave coordination ?

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case, zookeeper can be used for leader election and assigning the right token range to the node when a new node joins. In very similar case previous version of Fb Cassandra used to use zookeeper for same reason however later community got rid of it. Read the Replication and Bootstrapping section of [this](https://docs.datastax.com/en/articles/cassandra/cassandrathenandnow.html).